# Why is there a difference between int *func(…..); and int (*func)(….)? Does it have something to do with the operator *?

Tags: c, grammar

As is known, there is a difference between `int *func(…..);` and `int (*func)(….);`. The former defines a function, while the latter defines a pointer to a function. But I'm wondering why there is a difference? Is the operator `*` by default attached to what is before it?

Comment: Without the parentheses the `*` is part of the return type, so `int *`, with the parentheses it is part of the type of the variable (changing `func` from function to function pointer). The same rule as for `int *arr[]` and `int (*arr)[]`.

Comment: "I have tried to asked chatGPT for help"  Don't ask notorious liars for help...

Comment: @Lundin, It wasn't wrong. It's easy to think of `(* ... )` as one thing.

Comment: @ikegami Declarations/initialization in C kind of follows the same rules as operator precedence in expressions. No two operators "belong together" or "are attached".

Comment: @Lundin, Except that's clearly false. Removing the parens would mean something else. They are required here (because of precedence rules). Both are required together for function pointers. It's not like it's sometimes, like around addition.

Comment: @ikegami The formal syntax of a declarator is "pointer direct-declarator" where "pointer" is optional and expands to `*` whereas direct-declarator may expand to the form "identifier". The `*` and the identifier are what belong together in order to form a declaration.

Comment: @Lundin And? That's doesn't change anything I said. Specifically, I'm not saying that your way is wrong and that there's only one way to see it. I'm in fact saying there are (at least) two.

Comment: This is just a matter of precedence in the syntax.  The `()` in a function declaration argument list binds more tightly than `*`, so if you want to associate the `*` with the identifier, parentheses are needed.  Without them, `*func(...)` is equivalent to `*(func(...))`.  This is quite different from `(*func)(...)`.  In particular, `int *func(...)` is a function that returns a pointer to an `int`, while  `int (*func)(...)` is a pointer to a function that returns an `int`.

Comment: " But I'm wondering why there is a difference?" Are you asking for a formal syntax description? Or are you asking why it was made like this?

Comment: There's a difference because they are different things. If they used the same syntax, C wouldn't know which one you want.

Answer (score 2):

The order of precedence defined in the C grammar binds post fix operators such as `++`, `()` and `[]` stronger than prefix operators such as `*`.  This explains why:

- `int *func(void)` defines a (function named `func` of no arguments returning a) pointer to `int`; whereas
- `int (*func)(void)` defines a variable named `func` that is a pointer to (a function of no arguments returning an `int`).

To parse a C definition, you can use the spiral rule: start from the symbol `func`, parse the postfix operators, then the prefix operators inside the `()` and again from what follows the `)` and then what precedes the `(`.